# clicked "hide" on django debug toolbar and it completely disappeared from Firefox

Tags: django, firefox, hide, toolbar

Currently using Django 1.6, south and django-debug-toolbar 1.0.1

Today I clicked 'hide' and it completely disappeared, it did not revert to the little tab on the right hand corner of the screen.  This happens on and Firefox but not on Chrome or Opera.  Firefox don't have any ad-blockers or anything like that installed.

EDIT: Firefox 'private windows' don't have this problem either.  The only extensions I have installed are 'firebug', 'pagespeed', 'yslow' and 'pocket'.

I searched for it in firebug to see if it is still there and this is what I found:

`<div id="djDebugToolbar" style="display: none;">`

When I delete the `style="display: none;"` tag within Firebug (or change it to `style="display: block;"`) then the toolbar comes back, when I click hide then the toolbar disappears and the `style="display:none;"` returns.

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same problem, but then with Chrome instead of Firefox.

In Chrome I clicked 'hide' once and I couldn't see the toolbar any longer. In Firefox, IE or Chrome's private browsing mode, the toolbar was shown without an issue.

Can you try cleaning your browser's cookies (or at least the ones for 127.0.0.1 or the host you're trying to see DJDT on)? For me, that fixed the issue.

Comment: Clearing cookies for the site fixed it for me too! I've been manually turning off the "display: none" property on the toolbar for several weeks. Derp!

Answer (score 0):

There's another way to do this, but this is for Django 3.0 and higher. By shutting off the server in the terminal and running the server again with "python manage.py runserver" it is back again.